# Running "del" NPM dependency from package.json script on Windows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp, package.json

I want a script in package.json named `"foobar"` that executes `"del node_modules"`, using the devDependency `"del": "^1.1.1"`, on Windows. The problem is that when I execute `npm run foobar`, the DOS "del" command runs instead of the NPM dependency `"del": "^1.1.1"`.

How can I run `"del": "^1.1.1"` from the command line when `"del": "^1.1.1"` is not installed globally?

Comment: moral of the story: don't install packages that cause name conflicts with OS utilities. Use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) instead? `"clean": "rimraf node_modules && rimraf build"` or something to clean out all your things.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. I had rimraf installed but saw that it's deprecated so tried replacing with "del," which rimraf says to use instead. Ugh.

Comment: where did you see it was deprecated? (I don't see any deprecation information for it anywhere, and isaac is usually pretty thorough!)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf/commit/7d0ba5d970f8c10b1ac6e719b1b7458b3fe5bb22#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R4) (for gulp)

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was referring to: https://github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf (gulp-rimraf). My bad.

Answer (score 3):

For command-line scenarios you can use [del-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del-cli) on top of `del`.
See the usage section on github